# Warning en Equals supuestamente nulo

Tags: java, android, menú

Tengo el siguiente Warning:

> Method invocation 'equals' may produce
>   'java.lang.NullPointerException'

Mi línea de código es la siguiente:

```
    if(menu.getItem(2).getIcon().getConstantState().equals(ContextCompat.getDrawable(fragmentActivity, R.mipmap.buscar_warning).getConstantState()))
```

Nunca me ha generado error, pero no entiendo del todo el warning, lo que estoy haciendo, es comparar el ícono de mi menú superior con una imagen que tengo en el directorio `mipmap`.

EDITO:

Lo mismo me pasa en los otros `if` con `menu.getItem(0)` y `menu.getItem(1)`

EDITO2:

Esto ocurre en mi método "filtrarChecks" donde guardo todo lo seleccionado en "Ordenar Por", "Filtrar por" o "Busqueda" (esto depende de los RadioButtom, CheckButtom y un EditText que posee un menú), y lo paso por un adaptador que reodena y/o oculta elementos de un ExpandableListView

EDITO3:

**Necesito hacer esta igualdad afuera del método onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){...}   No se insista. Este es mi onOptionsItemSelected**

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        this.item = item;
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.ordenar_item:
                //Desaparecen todos los demás
                if(filtrosLl.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
                    filtrosLl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if(busquedaMet.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
                    busquedaMet.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                //Aparece/desaparece Ordenar Por
                if(prioridadesLl.getVisibility()==View.GONE) {
                    prioridadesLl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else{
                    prioridadesLl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                return true;
            case R.id.filtrar_item:
                //Desaparecen todos los demás
                if(prioridadesLl.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
                    prioridadesLl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if(busquedaMet.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
                    busquedaMet.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                //Aparece/desaparece Filtrar Por
                if(filtrosLl.getVisibility()==View.GONE) {
                    filtrosLl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    //mensajeFiltrosTv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }else {
                    filtrosLl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    /*if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(mensajeFiltrosTv.getText()))
                        mensajeFiltrosTv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);*/
                }
                return true;
            case R.id.buscar_item:
                //Desaparecen todos los demás
                if(prioridadesLl.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
                    prioridadesLl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if(filtrosLl.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
                    filtrosLl.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                //Aparece/desaparece Buscar Por
                if(busquedaMet.getVisibility()==View.GONE) {
                    busquedaMet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else{
                    busquedaMet.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                return true;
            case android.R.id.home:
                fragmentActivity.finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: con este cambio en tu código aún obtienes el mensaje "Method invocation 'equals' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'" si no es así ahora cual es el problema que surge?

Comment: Hola, alguna respuesta respondio a tu problema? @Maguz

Answer (score 1):

El `warning` indica que no es una buena practica de programación asignar los valores del ID de forma constante:

```
 menu.getItem(2);
```

porque el ID podría existir o no. Lo recomendable es obtener el ID de una manera más segura(que no cause una excepción en tiempo de ejecución):

```
menu.findItem(R.id.miMenu);
```

ó:

```
item.getItemId();
```

Un ejemplo del segundo caso:

mi_menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/hello"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_hello"
          android:title="@string/shello" />
    <item android:id="@+id/bye"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_bye"
          android:title="@string/sbye" />
</menu>
```

**En el `Activity`**

Inflar el Menu Resource:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Asignar una acción para cada elemento del menú:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.hello:
        sayHello();
        return true;
    case R.id.bye:
        sayBye();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: ambas llamadas: menu.findItem(R.id.miMenu); y item.getItemId(); no solucionan el warning

Answer (score 0):

Como tu bien dices es un `warning` por lo tanto es un advertencia. La advertencia hace referencia a que para tu menú, específicamente para los items puede estar definido :

- item 1
- item 2
- item 3

Pero te advierte porque ***PUEDE*** existir la posibilidad de que para el método `getItem(i)` no haya referencia para dicho indice y esto podría causar una `exception` de nulo. Puedes poner `getItem(1000)` y te dará la advertencia, sin embargo en tiempo de ejecución tu aplicación generara dicha `exception`

**EDICION**

Según mi perspectiva, hacer desaparecer ese `warning` mediante código lo veo muy muy difícil, tampoco entiendo la intensión del ocultarlo, cuando no afecta en nada en solo una *advertencia*, sin embargo si no quieres verlo puedes ir :

```
Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Annotations
```

Buscas `Warning` (penultima opcion) y sacas el check a la opcion `Vertical ruler`

Comment: y como valido que exista el icono en el menú y asi quitar el warning?

Comment: más que el icono de tu item, es el ITEM en cuestion el que lanza el warning, al parecer no se puede obtener la cantidad total de los items en tu menu

Comment: @Maguz de todas formas, a que hace referencia tu codigo? que es lo que pretendes conseguir con ese if y que hacer en caso de que se cumpla?

Comment: @ sioesi PRIMERO: es un filtro, si hay alguno activado, cambio el icono por uno con el fondo de otro color.

En esta parte basicamente y resumiento mucho, estoy consultando si hay algun filtro activado, es decir, si esta puesto este icono con color

Comment: creo que no hay manera de verificar sin un warning esa información, ya que el filtro se lo aplicas en tiempo de ejecución, por ende no hay un VALOR definido para ese filtro.

Comment: como dijiste al principio, "al parecer no se puede obtener la cantidad total de los items en tu menu", opino lo mismo, ojala alguien sepa como

Comment: @Maguz donde quieres aplicar este codigo especificamente?

Comment: en mi  método "filtrarChecks" guardo todo lo seleccionado en "Ordenar Por", "Filtrar por" o "Busqueda" (esto depende de los RadioButtom, CheckButtom y un EditText que posee un menú), y lo paso por un adaptador que reodena y/o oculta elementos de un ExpandableListView

Comment: Pero cual es el fin de tu codigo? Sigo sin entenderlo @Maguz

Comment: Tengo una ExpandableListView, con 600 elementos. Mi código es *funcional*, y me permite filtrar, ordenar y/o buscar elementos de forma inmediata. Es decir si activo el filtro "Ordenar por FechaInscripción" se ordenan los 600 datos. El tema del warning es solo eso, una advertencia, que no afecta en nada, es solo que quiero quitarla sin agregar una etiqueta.

Comment: entiendo, entonces tu en tu menu, seleccionar el orden y se debe ordenar altiro?+

Comment: sí, y si filtro, tambien es instantaneo, y si escribo en el buscador, tambien es inmediato a medida que ingresa texto

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50554/discussion-between-sioesi-and-maguz).

Comment: esta bloqueado, y me imposible iniciar el chat.

Comment: por que no puedes iniciar el chat @Maguz

Comment: @Maguz edite mi respuiesta

Answer (score 0):

No debes obtener los elementos del menú por medio del indice, ya que puedes usar un indice que no corresponde a un elemento y puede marcar como menciona el mensaje:

> Method invocation 'equals' may produce
>   'java.lang.NullPointerException'

Es recomendable obtener los items de acuerdo a su id, ejemplo:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu1:

      // if(menu.getItem(2).getIcon().getConstantState().equals(ContextCompat.getDrawable(fragmentActivity, R.mipmap.buscar_warning).getConstantState()))

     if (item.getIcon().getConstantState().equals(ContextCompat.getDrawable(fragmentActivity, R.mipmap.buscar_warning).getConstantState()))
      ...
      ...



        return true;
    case R.id.menu2:

     if (item.getIcon().getConstantState().equals(ContextCompat.getDrawable(fragmentActivity, R.mipmap.imagen2).getConstantState()))
      ...
      ...



        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
  }   

}
```

Comment: claro, así lo tengo en el método onOptionsItemSelected(), pero la comparación de la que estoy consultando es en otra función... (es en un filtro, ordenar por y un buscador)

Comment: Implemente el if que sugeriste en otro método (distinto de onOptionsItemSelected) y me sigue marcando el warning en "equals"

Answer (score 0):

Lo que entiendo es que esta parte:

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(fragmentActivity, R.mipmap.buscar_warning)
```

Puede resultar que devuelve un valor `null`, por lo que es posible que al querer obtener lo siguiente: `.getConstantState()`, te lance el error de `NullPointeException`.

Deberías primero asegurarte que la primer parte no te devuelva null:

```
if(ContextCompat.getDrawable(fragmentActivity, R.mipmap.buscar_warning) != null && menu.getItem(2).getIcon().getConstantState().equals(ContextCompat.getDrawable(fragmentActivity, R.mipmap.buscar_warning).getConstantState()))
```

Comment: No, para el equals la parte que comentas es indiferente, el problema esta en que `menu.getItem(2).getIcon().getConstantState()` puede ser nulo y por eso al hacer `.equals` de el NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

El warning aparece porque alguno de los elementos de la cadena `menu.getItem(2).getIcon().getConstantState()` esta anotado como `@Nullable`.

Una anotación `@Nullable` significa que un valor de retorno legítimo del método podría ser null. Por lo tanto debes comprobar esta condición antes de llamar el siguiente metodo en la cadena. Por ejemplo si `getIcon()` es el método anotado con `@Nullable` puedes modificar la condicional de la manera siguiente:

```
Drawable icon = menu.getItem(2).getIcon();
if (icon != null && icon.getConstantState().equals(ContextCompat.getDrawable(fragmentActivity, R.mipmap.buscar_warning).getConstantState()))
```

Es recomendable que hagas caso a esta advertencia. Ya que en algún momento pudiera darse el caso y la aplicación se cerraría sin ningún tipo de explicación. Eso puede dañar la imagen de la app